# Adding Previous Row to Current Row - sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table below that is a result of many temp tables and it involves join and order by clause.

```
Type                Col1       Col2         Col3        Col4       Col5
Within 30 days      493868      426428      401194      268929      399480
Within 60 days      745         13118       35577       31577       30536
Within 90 days      NULL        28222       27312       45085       10432
Within 120 days     NULL        12039       13999       38239       11777
Grater than120 days NULL        14806       16531       110783      13091
Blank               NULL        NULL         NULL       NULL        29297
Total               494613      494613       494613     494613      494613
```

I want the output as below:
The current row value should be previous row value + current value..soo on until it matched the total.

```
Type                    Col1       Col2         Col3       Col4     Col5
Within 30 days          493868     426428       401194     268929      399480
Within 60 days           494613    439546       436771      300506     430016
Within 90 days           494613    467768       464083      345591     440448
Within 120 days          494613    479807       478082      383830     452225
Greater than 120 days    494613    494613       494613      494613     465316
Blank                    494613    494613       494613      494613     494613
Total                    494613    494613       494613      494613     494613
```

Since I have used orderby clause I cannot use temptable and derived table.Kindly help.I have used the query:

`select e.[type],o.[Col1],h.[Col2],s.[Col3],d.[Col4],e.[Col5]
     from #table1 e
    left outer join #table2 d on e.[type]=d.[type]
    left outer join #table3 s on e.[type]=s.[type]
    left outer join #table4 h on e.[type]=h.[type]
    left outer join #table5 o on e.[type]=o.[type]
    order by case
    when e.[type] ='Within 30 days' then 1
    when e.[type] ='Within 60 days' then 2
    when e.[type] ='Within 90 days' then 3
    when e.[type] ='Within 120 days' then 4
    when e.[type] ='Greater than 120 days' then 5
    when e.[type] ='Blank' then 6
    else 7
    end`

Answer (score 5):

Use `SUM OVER()` window aggregate function to calculate running total

```
Select type,
        sum([Count(A)]) Over(order by order_col) as [Count(A)],
        sum([Count(B)]) Over(order by order_col) as [Count(B)],
        sum([Count(C)]) Over(order by order_col) as [Count(C)],
        sum([Count(D)]) Over(order by order_col) as [Count(D)],
        sum([Count(E)]) Over(order by order_col) as [Count(E)]
From your_result
```

You can add a `CASE` statement on top `sum over()` to avoid summing `type  = Total`

For Older Verions

```
SELECT type,
        cs.[Count(A)],
        cs.[Count(B)],
        cs.[Count(C)],
        cs.[Count(D)],
        cs.[Count(E)]
FROM   your_result t
        CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Count(A)]) [Count(A)],
                            Sum([Count(B)]) [Count(B)],
                            Sum([Count(C)]) [Count(C)],
                            Sum([Count(D)]) [Count(D)],
                            Sum([Count(E)]) [Count(E)]
                    FROM   your_result t1
                    WHERE  t1.order_col <= t.order_col) cs
```